Assign Azure Policy's depending on the subscription tag
I have a question and unfortunately I can't find anything explicit in the MS documentation.
We would like to use the Azure Policies to determine the location of the resource etc. via the subscription tag. For example, we have a tag on the subscription:
Location = North Europe
We cannot currently do it via different Management Groups because we only have general mgm groups such as Spoke etc. In addition, we do not want to maintain/inherit the tags for each resource.
I am afraid that I have already described the solution.
Do you have any suggestions or documentation?

Are you looking for an Azure policy to deploy resources in the subscription tag region?

If yes, The Azure Policy cannot directly reference subscription-level tags, you can create a custom Azure Policy that enforces the location of resources based on a parameter. The parameter can be set manually to match the subscription tag value (North Europe).

Hello Venkat,
that's exactly what I mean. We currently have three different Azure regions and they are all in one management group. Currently we have said that all three regions can be created in any subscription.
Do you mean that you have to maintain the resource tags or what exactly do you mean by the parameters?


Assign Azure Policy's depending on the subscription tag

Azure Policy cannot directly reference subscription-level tags; however, you can create a custom azure policy that enforces the location of resources based on a parameter.
The parameter can be set manually to match the subscription tag value (North Europe).
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "field": "location",
      "notIn": [
        "[parameters('location')]"
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "location": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "location",
        "description": "Specify the allowed location for the resources."
      },
      "allowedValues": [
        "North Europe",
        "West Europe",
        "East US",
        "Southeast Asia"
      ],
      "defaultValue": "North Europe"
    }
  }
}

Azure Policy assignment

The policy restricts the resource if the location does not match the specified policy location. If they do not match, an error will be thrown.

The policy allows resource creation if the location is North Europe.


Hello Venkat,
thank you for the effort. However, with your solution we can only say again either you may select all regions in the subscription and not say example-south_africa may only roll out in africa and example-north_europe only in Europe correct?

Azure Policy does not directly allow for dynamic constraints based on resource names alone. However, you can achieve this with Azure Policy in combination with resource tags or naming conventions and a policy to enforce those rules

You can create a policy by specifying the name and region.
